# Regex for checking if a string has mismatched parentheses?

Tags: php, regex

In a PHP script, what regex should I use to check for mismatched parentheses in a string?  Things that I want to allow include:

- This is (ok)
- This (is) (ok)

Things I want to prevent:

- This is )bad(
- This is also (bad
- This is (bad (too)

Thanks!

Update:  You guys all rock.  Doing this with a regex seemed trickier than it should have, and these kinds of 2nd level answers are what makes stackoverflow beautiful.  Thanks for the links and the pseudocode.  I'm not sure who to give the answer to, so I apologize to everyone whose answers I can't accept.

Comment: Do you need arbitrary nested parentheses or you know for sure that there are no more than a fixed level (say 5 levels deep) of nesting possible in any input string?

Comment: Strings are limited to about 300 chars.  It is certainly possible to get 300 (s in a row though.  Ah, user input :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Regex is not the right tool for the job. Scan a string manually.

Pseudo-code:

```
depth = 0
for character in some_string:
    depth += character == '('
    depth -= character == ')'
    if depth < 0:
       break

if depth != 0:
   print "unmatched parentheses"
```

Answer (score 23):

You *can* do this with a regular expression -- PCRE, as used by PHP, allows recursive patterns. The PHP Manual gives an [example](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php#regexp.reference.recursive) that is almost exactly what you want:

```
\(((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*\)
```

This matches any correctly parenthesised substring as long as it begins and ends with parentheses. If you want to ensure the entire string is balanced, allowing strings like
"wiggedy(wiggedy)(wiggedy(wack))", here's what I came up with:

```
^((?:[^()]|\((?1)\))*+)$
```

Here's an explanation of the pattern, which may be more illuminating than obfuscatory:

```
^             Beginning of the string
(             Start the "balanced substring" group (to be called recursively)
  (?:         Start the "minimal balanced substring" group
    [^()]     Minimal balanced substring is either a non-paren character
    |         or
    \((?1)\)  a set of parens containing a balanced substring
  )           Finish the "minimal balanced substring" group
  *           Our balanced substring is a maximal sequence of minimal
              balanced substrings
  +           Don't backtrack once we've matched a maximal sequence
)             Finish the "balanced substring" pattern
$             End of the string
```

There are lots of considerations of efficiency and correctness that come up with these sorts of regexes. Be careful.

Comment: +1.  Perl can do it too via the (??{ code }) extension.  Many (most?) modern languages' "regular expression" engines are strictly more powerful than regular languages / DFAs.

Comment: Perl has the same (?R) subgroup. But this feature, as well as (?? { code }), are highly experimental, and the documentation states that their exact side effects are subject to change between versions. So for production code, don't try to use hacks in the finite automaton (PCRE).

Comment: Chris, do you have a reference for the "highly experimental" warning? The PCRE man page at http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt doesn't say this.

Comment: This is potentially a *very* dangerous feature. Use of the recursion flag can both cause catastrophic (PCRE-crashing) backtracking, as well as excessive (script-terminating) memory consumption if you use capturing groups. For a simple case like this, it is *far* better to not use regexes at all!

Comment: That's is true of regexes in general. Catastrophic backtracking can easily occur without using recursion. The best thing about regexes is their incredible power and flexibility. The worst thing about regexes is their incredible power and flexibility.

Comment: Expresso really barfs on both of those, though I respect BME's wisdom

Comment: My example uses a recursive pattern and a possessive quantifier. I don't think these are supported by the .Net framework, so no wonder Expresso is confused. (Though could replace the possessive '+' with a .Net nonbacktracking group.)

Comment: .Net has something called a balancing group, which apparently can be used to solve the balancing parentheses problem. It might even be more efficient that PCRE recursive groups.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to accomplish this with a regex.  Brace matching requires a recursive/counting feature that is not available in a regex.  You'll need a parser for this.

More details available here: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations.aspx

Comment: Recursion and counting ARE available features in some languages' regular expression engines, e.g. Perl's and PHP's.  See Bennett McElwee's answer.  Perl has a Regexp::Common::balanced module in CPAN that does this.

Comment: @Brian, this is more of a semantic argument but at the point a regex can do recursion, it's not actually a regex anymore.  It's a context free grammar.  I realize this really means nothing to most people though and recursion is quickly becoming a must have feature for regexes.

Comment: You're right, but I think in context of the OP's question, it's important to point out that whatever PHP calls a "regex" can actually do what he's asking it to do.  (Let's hope they are still called "regex" for a while, cfgex doesn't roll off the tongue as nicely.  :)

Comment: @Brian, I actually didn't realize that PHP regex's have recursive capabilities (usually work with the .Net version). cregex is awful.  I like modregex but that would confuse perl guys.  Maybe rrregex (recursive ready regex). You'd have to use a tony the tiger frosted flakes voice to say it though.

Answer (score 3):

Your examples don't include any nested parentheses… if you aren't concerned with nesting, then this can be done using the following expression:

```
^[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*$
```

This will match against all the strings in your "allow" list and fail against the strings in your "prevent" list. However, **it will also fail against any string with nested parentheses**.  e.g. "this (is (not) ok)"

As others have already pointed out, regular expressions are not the correct tool if you need to handle nesting.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with the fact that this is impossible with a REGEX.  You could do the following, though:

```
<?php

$testStrings = array( 'This is (ok)', 'This (is) (ok)', 'This is )bad(', 'This is also (bad', 'This is (bad (too)' );

foreach( $testStrings as $string ) {
    $passed = hasMatchedParentheses( $string ) ? 'passed' : 'did not pass';
    echo "The string $string $passed the check for matching parenthesis.\n";
}

function hasMatchedParentheses( $string ) {
    $counter = 0;
    $length = strlen( $string );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++ ) {
        $char = $string[ $i ];
        if( $char == '(' ) {
            $counter ++;
        } elseif( $char == ')' ) {
            $counter --;
        }
        if( $counter < 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $counter == 0;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend JaredPar's answer, it's not very difficult to solve without using a regex, just write a function that examines each character in the string and increments/decrements a counter. If you find a "(", increment it, and if you find a ")", decrement it. If the counter ever goes below 0, you can break, the string is invalid. When you've processed the whole string, if the counter isn't 0, there was an unmatched open parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

**Why it's not possible with a regex**

The other answers are all correct, but I just want to put in a plug for theoretical computer science... this is a case where knowing the theory gives an actual practical advantage.

A regex corresponds to a deterministic finite automaton (DFA), but paren matching require a context-free grammar, which can be realized as a finite automaton (PDA) but not by a DFA.

Because of this, without a lot of extra brain-work, we know that the answer is no, and we don't have to worry that there is something we're just overlooking.  So, you can be confident in the above answers, and not worry that the authors are just overlooking something when they give that answer.

Almost all compiler books will talk about this, here's a quick overview:

http://books.google.com/books?id=4LMtA2wOsPcC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=push-down+finite+automata&source=bl&ots=NisYwNO1r0&sig=ajaSHFXwpPOWG8IfbcfKoqzS5Wk&hl=en&ei=m26cSdf6DZGYsAPB-6SsAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=6&ct=result

Comment: This is not quite true. Regexes, as used in PHP and many other contexts, are not actually regular expressions in the formal sense. They add a whole lot of features that make them more useful and extend them beyond what real regular expressions can do. This is why the problem is solvable.

Comment: Hmm, what feature?  Do you have an example that will work on "((()))", "()()()", "(((", or "()))"?

Comment: The recursive subpattern feature. See my answer to this question, which correctly handles the four examples you give.

Answer (score 0):

Working php without regex:

```
function analyse($input){
    $len = strlen($input);
    $depth = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $depth += $input[$i] == '(';
        $depth -= $input[$i] == ')';
        if ($depth < 0) break;
    }
    if ($depth != 0) return false;
        else return true;
}
$check_nestled = analyse('(5 * 2) + ((2 + 2) - 4)');
if($check_nestled){
    // do stuff, everything is ok
}
```