# Validating parentheses for a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm giving my users the ability to create their own MySQL queries. Don't worry, I'm taking all the sql injection etc into account.

What I am wanting to do is validate the parentheses they use while creating their query...

So lets say they their query looks like this:

```
$string = '1 AND (2 OR 3) AND (4 AND (5 OR 6)';
```

See how they didn't close the open parenthesis before the number 4? Is there any regex I could run on this to validate any open or closed parentheses that haven't been added correctly?

I've been playing and searching everywhere but I have no idea how to make this work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562606/regex-for-checking-if-a-string-has-mismatched-parentheses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jayantha! Here's the solution I found from clicking your link:

```
$string = '1 AND (2 OR 3) AND (4 AND (5 OR 6)';

if (!preg_match("/^((?:[^()]|\((?1)\))*+)$/", $string, $matches))
    echo 'Your parentheses are wrong!';
```