# `re` module match text between two pairs of brackets in Python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

For example, I have a string like `'(10 + 20) / (10 + 20)'`.

And now I want to match `(10 + 20)`. So I write a script like this:

```
text = '(10 + 20) / (10 + 20)'                                                                                                          
test1 = re.findall(r'(.*)', text)                                            
test2 = re.findall(r'(.+?)', text)                                           

for i in test1:                                                              
    print(i, end='')                                                         
else:                                                                        
    print()                                                                  

for i in test2:                                                              
    print(i, end='')                                                         
else:                                                                        
    print()
```

And the output is this:

```
(10 + 20) / (10 + 20)                                                                                                                       
(10 + 20) / (10 + 20)
```

I don't understand, doesn't `.+?` not greedy?

Comment: You need to escape `(` and `)` to match literal parentheses.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks, it works. but `r'(.+?)'` is raw string right?

Comment: Ok, let me answer this.

Comment: You probably want `r'\([^\(].+?\)'` otherwise it will match `((2+3)) -> ((2+3)`

Comment: @Andrey I've just tried this, but no difference.

Comment: @KevinGuan your regex will handle brackets incorrectly. Try this `((2+3) + (4+5))`

Comment: @Andrey Oh, you're right! thanks.

Comment: related: [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279)

Comment: related: [Regex for checking if a string has mismatched parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562606/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The round brackets in a regex pattern must be escaped with `\` to match literal round brackets:

```
test2 = re.findall(r'\(.+?\)', text)
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/lOFgcC)

A "raw" string literal does not mean that you do not have to escape special regex characters but it means you can use just *one* backslash to escape them, not two.

See this excerpt from [*6.2.5.8. Raw String Notation*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation):

> Raw string notation `(r"text")` keeps regular expressions sane. Without it, every backslash (`'\'`) in a regular expression would have to be prefixed with another one to escape it. For example, the two following lines of code are functionally identical:
>
> `>>>`
>      `>>> re.match(r"\W(.)\1\W", " ff ")`
>      `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match=' ff '>`
>      `>>> re.match("\\W(.)\\1\\W", " ff ")`
>      `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match=' ff '>`

The docs say *usually*, but it does not mean you have to use raw string literals every time.

It is true that `.+?` is a lazy pattern, it means *match 1 or more characters other than a newline, but as few as possible*.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now :)

Comment: There is one thing of interest in Python: when an escape sequence cannot be parsed as an escape sequence, the backslash is treated as a literal. `'\('` and `'\\('` will be printed the same, and no error will be thrown. So, using a raw string literal here is optional, but it is still the best practice.

Comment: So whatever if I need use raw string or not, but use raw string is always a good choice. Right?

Comment: @KevinGuan: Unless you use Unicode or very simple patterns, yes. I added more description from the Python 3 re reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\([^()]+\)', '(10 + 20) / (10 + 20)')
['(10 + 20)', '(10 + 20)']
```

The dialect of regular expressions used in the `re` module can't support arbitrary nested parentheses therefore `[^()]` that matches everything except parentheses is always valid here.

Note: you don't need to escape `()` inside `[]` that defines a set of characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `(` and `)` like this:

```
`\(.*\)`
```

and this

```
`\(.+?\)`.
```

The first one will match until it finds the last possible `)`, the other one i non-greedy and will stop at the first `)`

Comment: That is, but @stribizhev has answered me.