# Check if every brace inside a expression has a matching closing brace

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have encountered a problem in which I have to evaluate if every brace used inside a mathematical expression has a matching closing brace.

For example:

- Valid expression : `[(a+b)+b]`
- Non valid expression : `[(a+b}+b]`

Below is my code:

```
str1 = input()
matches = {'(':')','[':']','{':'}'}
open = ['(','[','{']
close = [')',']','}']
track = []
negative = 0
for c in str1:
    if c in open:
        track.append(c)
    elif c in close:
        if c != matches[track[-1]]:
            negative = 1
            break
        else:
            del track[-1]
if negative == 1: 
    print ("False")
else:
    print ("True")
```

Is there a better way of doing it such as using regular expressions? Is my code good enough or can it be optimised?

Comment: Note that this code throws an error for an input like ')', as track is empty at the beginning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for checking if a string has mismatched parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562606/regex-for-checking-if-a-string-has-mismatched-parentheses)

Comment: With reference to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562606/regex-for-checking-if-a-string-has-mismatched-parentheses], regex is not appropriate for the task. The way you are doing it is ideal.

Comment: @Windmill: you should read the second answer to the question you linked. However the re module doesn't have the recursion feature but the pypi regex module has it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with your expression, you can easily code a [LL Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) or a [Shunting-Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). They are the two most common solutions for this kind of problem (the "parsing" problem).

Answer (score 0):

A stack would work:

```
def validate(_str):
    braces = set("[](){}")
    opening = set("[({")
    closing = {"]":"[", ")":"(", "}":"{"}
    stack = list()

    for _char in _str:
        if _char in opening:
            stack.append(_char)
        elif _char in closing:
            if closing[_char] == stack[-1]:
                stack.pop()
            else:
                return False
    return True

print("Should be False:",validate("(a+b}+b"))
print("Should be True:",validate("(a+b)+b"))
print("Should be True:",validate("(a+[b-c+{d+e}])+b"))
print("Should be False:",validate("(a+]b-c+{d+e}])+b"))
```